# Thymeleaf get the previous object by index

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How can I get the previous object by index (e.g. *iterStat-1*)?

This code is based on the thymeleaf tutorial example.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>IN STOCK</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="prod,iterStat : ${prods}" th:class="${iterStat.odd}? 'odd'">
        <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
        <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
        <td th:text="${prod.inStock}? #{true} : #{false}">yes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want something like the following.

```html
<td th:text="${prod[iterStat-1].price}"></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with

```
<td th:unless="${iterStat.first}" th:text="${prods[iterStat.index-1].price}"></td>
```

`th:unless="${iterStat.first}"` will not render cell for the first element, so that you don't try to obtain element of index **-1** (would results in exception).

Comment: If it works as you've expected please consider accepting the answer ;)